# GWT : MenuBar Submenu position / Z index

Tags: gwt, submenu, menubar

Im trying to display a Submenu when im hover a menuitem but my Submenu is on a wrong position and it is under my Menu.

how can I set the Position of my Submenu or change the z index of the Sumenu (popup)

Answer (score 1):

As long as your submenu class extends the com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject class, you can give it a style name. (All widgets do this). And then you can set the z-index of that style in a css file:

**Java:**

```
MySubMenuClass submenu = new MySubMenuClass();
submenu.addStyleName("subMenuStyle");
```

**CSS:**

```
.subMenuStyle{
  z-index: 50;  // or any other value > 0
}
```

Alternatively, you can hardcode the z-index in java (not recommended, because for every change to the value of your z-index you will have to recompile your entire GWT application instead of simply exchanging the CSS file and refreshing). The submenu class still needs to extend UIObject for this to work.

**Java:**

```
submenu.getElement().getStyle().setZIndex( 50 );
```